# Memory Leak : org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, jaxb, webservicetemplate

[image]During the load testing of invoking the SAOP Endpoint We were using Spring related: WebServiceTemplate

```
JAXBElement<GetXYZCostMatrixResponse> resp = (JAXBElement<GetXYZCostMatrixResponse>) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
```

On commenting this line I was not getting Out of Memory issue

Around 16 MB per each request getting retained

Can any body tell is it because or Jaxb2Marshaller (default implementation) ?

Comment: I think you need to analyze it yourself. See [Tools for OutOfMemoryError java heap space analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867140/tools-for-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-analysis).

Comment: Lots of byte[] were cumulated by the webServiceTemplate invocation, I assume we need have logic for http://javaetmoi.com/2014/02/memory-leak-client-cxf-attachment/

Comment: •org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer @ 0x8f575da0 - 16,777,736 (1.02%) bytes.  60 conncurrent requests in ramup : 5 seconds